# How to extract integer (seconds), from three possible different inputs?

Tags: regex, scala, playframework

As I described in the title, how can I get the integer data from a string input what contain ints and chars.

Possible inputs for the function are:
("1 min." ... "9 min."),
("11:59" ... "12:00") and
(">>"), what I can assume is 0.

I came up with this solution, but returns me exact string as input. How to get only the number existing in this patern.

```
def toSeconds(time : String) : String = {
    val pattern = """(\d+) min.""".r
    val pattern2 = """(\d+):(\d+).""".r

    if(pattern.findFirstIn(time) != "None")
    {
        pattern.findFirstIn(time).toString.concat("h") 
    }
    if (pattern2.findFirstIn(time) != "None")
    {
        pattern2.findFirstIn(time).toString.concat("x")
    }
    if (time == ">>") 0.toString
    else time
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
time match {
  case pattern(m) => s"${m}h"
  case pattern2(h,m) => s"${h}h${m}"
  case ">>" => "0"
  case _ => time
}
```

Comment: Works great, maybe with a little fix at pattern 2 is m, shows only first digit: Eg. input = 11:15 will result 11:1

Comment: You need to escape the dot - change "." to "\." because in regular expressions, the dot means any character, so it swallows up the digit. This is what you'd want: """(\d+):(\d+)\.""".r

Comment: using pattern2 = """(\d+):(\d+)""".r with call toSeconds("21:14") throws me is malformed at ":14". Why is that? Also matching with """(\d+):(\d+)\.""".r returns the default case (case _ => time). Alternative to match this 24h format? Thanks!

Comment: The colon is possibly a bad character, "MalformedInputException thrown when an input byte sequence is not legal for given charset, or an input character sequence is not a legal sixteen-bit Unicode sequence."

Comment: You could replace the : with \D just to say it's anything that's not a digit.

Comment: You can replace the \. with \D? to say there may or may not be a non-digit letter.